# Активация профиля application.properties в зависимости от среды запуска

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-mvc, java-ee

Приложение разрабатывается и тестируется на хосте под Windows и должно запускаться в контейнере Docker.
Соответственно в Docker-compose запускается отдельный сервис с БД, параметры подключения к которому отличаются от параметров подключения на хосте под Windows.
Чтобы решить проблему запуска приложения с разными параметрами в разных средах был найден следующий способ.
Прописываем переменные среды в файле Docker-compose:

```
services:
 
  authorizationService:
    image: tomcat  
    volumes:
        - E:\Authorization_service_prjct\war_arсhive:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
    environment:
        - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: application-server 
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://database:3306/db_users?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
        - DB_USER: root
        - DB_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
        - "8888:8080"
    links:
        - "database:db_users"
  
  database:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: db_users
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3316:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
```

Создаем 3 файла профиля properties:

1. тот, что должен грузиться 1-ым и из которого мы берем данные какой файл properties нам нужно будет использовать, в нем же прописываем и какой дефолтный - **application.properties**:

   spring.config.name=application
   spring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE:application-local.properties}
2. файл properties с настройками для контейнера Docker - **application-server.properties**:

   spring.config.name=application-server
   spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
   spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
   spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   spring.jpa.show-sql=true
   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
3. файл properties с настройками для локального сервера - **application-local.properties**:

   spring.config.name=application-local
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_users?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
   spring.datasource.username=root
   spring.datasource.password=root
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   spring.jpa.show-sql=true
   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

По идее должно работать следующим образом:

1. грузится файл application.properties
2. параметру spring.profiles.active присваивается значение переменной среды SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE или дефолтное значение, если данная переменная не определена
3. по свойству spring.profiles.active определяется какой должен использоваться файл properties

Но тест запуска на локалке выдал ошибку с загрузкой Datasourse:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProper
> ties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable
> driver class at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProper
> ties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:234) at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProper
> ties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:1 75) at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfig
> uration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfig
> uration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeM
> ethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Del
> egatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiatio
> nStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ... 88
> more

Т.е. не работает - загрузка файлов properties идет не как планировалось.

В чем ошибка, что я неверно понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что проблема в неправильном значении параметра `spring.profiles.active`. Он принимает название профиля (`local`, `server`), а не файла или части файла. Вот как должно быть:

```yaml
environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: server
```

и

```
spring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE:local}
```